# how to detect a set of string after a " in python

Tags: python

I have a TXT File with a lot of information (In different lines).

```
Line 1: Roman could not buy sugar "Ran out of gas 
Line 2: Sugar was sold "In packets" cartridge
```

My question is: I have a strip, and a split to identify each word etc.
but what If I now want to replace anything between "" into a 1 please see example:

```
Line 1: Roman could not buy sugar 1
Line 2: Sugar was sold 1 cartridge
```

I need help converting anything after a " to a 1 and anything between two " into 1.

Going to add my current code:

```
revcheck = ['a','b','c','d']

for linea in lineas:
    numlin += 1
    print("linea " + str(numlin) + ": ", end=' ')
    linea = linea.strip()
    lista = linea.split()

    for a in lista:
        if a in revcheck:
            print ("Aceptado", end=' ')
        elif EsNumero(a): #This function checks to see if its an number
            print ("Aceptado", end=' ')
        else:
            print ("Denegado("+ a + ")",end=' ')

    print()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a a text file with a lot of lines so first of all I am looking for specific words
such as apple pie green red etc... SO I have these words stored in an array and anytime I see this word in any text I Change it to FOUND, but now I want anything in between " to be selected as well, and not sure how to begin.

Comment: Have you tried working with regex?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you can use strip and split to find the characters  of interest, but you need to change them. have you tried `.replace()` ?
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace

Comment: I would like to use RegEx, but not sure if its going to be compatible with my current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will replace everything between and after " with 1

```
txt = """\
Line 1: Roman could not buy sugar "Ran out of gas 
Line 2: Sugar was sold "In packets" cartridge\
"""

def my_strip(x):
    # If there's just one " in line replace everything after it with 1
    if x.count('"') == 1:
        return x[:x.index('"')] + '1'
    # Otherwise find first and second " and replace whats between them with 1
    return x[:x.index('"')] + '1' + x[x.index('"', x.index('"')+1)+1:]

for i in txt.splitlines():
    # As longest as there are " in current line (i) keep replacing them with 1
    while '"' in i:
        i = my_strip(i)
    print(i)
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: I commented code, if you're still uncertain about something let me know.

Comment: Thanks, I will implement it an let you know.

Comment: Its a bit difficult to implement in what I have, can I show you what I have ?

Comment: Sure, add it to your main post

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions:

```
import re

def replace_quotes_with_ones(s):
    return re.sub(r'".*?("|$)', '1', s)
```

Comment: Quick question, is that compatible with my Code?  like right now there is a for cycle that reads line per line and String by String.

Comment: It's just a question of calling the function `replace_quotes_with_ones` at the appropriate time. When in your code do you want to replace quotes with 1? Call the function at that place, and use the value it returns instead of the original string.

Comment: So instead of spliting the line into different strings, you suggest to first examine the entire line for quotation mark and if nothing was found then spliting the whole string?

Comment: The function I wrote takes a string, and returns the string with anything between or after quotation marks replaced with a '1'. It's up to you to decide when you want to use this; I can't tell you what you want your code to do.